# best way to implement ManyToManyField check?

Tags: django

Want to create a `Song` object. How do I check if this `Song` object is in a particular user's `UserProfile` to avoid repetition?

tried this but threw me an error `argument of type 'QuerySet' is not iterable`;

```
songs_available = user.userprofile.liked_songs.all()
if not song in songs_available:
   user.userprofile.liked_songs.add(song)
```

`models.py`

```
class Song(models.Model):
track_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
artiste_name= models.CharField(
max_length=200)
album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null=True, default=None, related_name = 
"songs")

class Meta:
    db_table="Song"

def __str__(self):
    return self.track_name


class UserProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None , null= True)
liked_songs = models.ManyToManyField("Song", null=True , default=None,  
related_name="users_that_liked_me")

class Meta:
    db_table = "UserProfile"

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

`views.py` (part of it)

```
 song, created = Song.objects.get_or_create(track_name = track,
 artiste_name = artist,
 album = album)
```

wanted to try `if created` but that only checks for the song model as many users could have the same song, it doesnt really help

Comment: .add() will not create duplicates but fail silently https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: The m:n relationship is with the user and song models?

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna it’s with the `UserProfile` and `Songs` model

Comment: So you want to check for the user currently logged in?

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna i use `user = User.objects.get(pk = request.session["pk"])` in the current view to get the user I want because I store the `pk` of a user I created in a session in another view.

Comment: @iklinac Had no idea `.add()` does not create duplicates. Thanks!

Comment: @kweks45 if you found the solution please share it

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, because I have improved your code

```
class Song(models.Model):
   track_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   artiste_name= models.CharField(
   max_length=200)
   album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete= models.CASCADE, null=True, 
   related_name="songs")     


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null= True)
    liked_songs = models.ManyToManyField("Song"related_name="users_that_liked_me")
```

Comment: here one song can't be in multiple albums. so to user foreignkey instead of manytomany is bad idea.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the changes you made? And why you made them? And how it helps my question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

refer to Django's docs for many-to-many field management.

here you can't directly add a many-to-many fields.

first, you need to create an object then add many-to-many data to it.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: I think I know how to add data to a M2M field, my question is, how do I check to see if an object already exists in a M2M field.

Answer (score 0):

So according to the Django Docs, as @iklinac stated in the comments, `.add()` prevents duplicate creation when populating a many to many field, as in my case. Eventually solved the problem like this.

```
  song, created = Song.objects.get_or_create(track_name = track,
  artiste_name = artist,
  album = album)

  user.userprofile.liked_songs.add(song)
```

All other code in my question remains the same.